# Trying to create an unconventional book

Tags: margins, multicol, book-design, a0poster

I'm trying to create an 'unconventional' document. By 'unconventional' I am talking about a book with the following characteristics:

1. pages in size a3 or a2 or a1 or a0 and 'landscape' orientation
2. the lower margins with a distance of 1cm from the bottom of the page
3. the upper margins with 1cm distance from the upper page border
4. the left margins with a distance of 1cm from the left page border
5. the right margins with 1cm distance from the right border of the page
6. The number of columns of the pages of the 'book' controllable. That is, I can choose whether the pages of the book have either 5 columns or 6 columns or 7 columns ...
7. The distance between the columns is controllable. Let's say, no bigger than 1cm.
8. That I could do a column break when I wanted with a command (`\columnbreak`  for example).
9. That the document does not adjust the vertical length of the column automatically.

I tried to use the code below but I did not succeed. A fatal error occurs. When I try to use the a0poster format, the following undesirable things happen:

1. I have no control under the upper and lower margins.
2. The vertical size of the speakers adjusts automatically.
3. Line spacing is too long.

**Thanks in advance for the contributions.**

```
    \documentclass[10pt,landscape,a3paper]{extbook}
%------Margins and columns ----------------------------
\usepackage[bottom=1.0cm,top=1.0cm,left=1.0cm,right=1.0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol} % This is so we can have multiple columns of text side-by-side
\columnsep=20pt % This is the amount of white space between the columns in the book.
%------PACKAGES FOR WRITTEN IN PORTUGUESE-------------------
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
%------PACKAGES OF AMERICAN MATHEMATICAL SOCIETY------------
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsxtra}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
%------MATH FONTS PACKAGES----------------------------------
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[mathscr]{eucal}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
%------TIKZ PACKAGES----------------------------------------
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%-----PACKAGE TO PUT THE CAPTIONS IN PICTURES---------------
\usepackage{caption}
\setlength{\captionmargin}{25pt}
%-----PACKAGE TO COMMENTS-----------------------------------
\usepackage{comment}
%-----PACKAGES FOR customize INDEX--------------------------
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{tocvsec2}
\usepackage{makeidx} 
%------ BibTeX and bibliographystyle------------------------
\usepackage{natbib}
%------ Outers packages-------------------------------------
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{upref}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[active]{srcltx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
%------- packet to write inside colored boxes-----
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\definecolor{cinza}{gray}{0.95}
%\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=cinza,arc=0.0pt,outer arc=0.0pt,colframe=black,boxrule=0.0pt]
%\end{tcolorbox}
%
%----------------------------------------------------------
\newtheorem{theorem}[subsection]{Teorema}
\newtheorem{definition}[subsection]{Definição}
\newtheorem{lema}[subsection]{Lema}
\newtheorem{proposition}[subsection]{Proposição}
\newtheorem{observation}[subsection]{Observação}
\newtheorem{notation}[subsection]{Notação}
\newtheorem{corollary}[subsection]{Corolário}
\newtheorem{exercise}{Exercício}
\newtheorem{exemple}[section]{Exemplo}
\newtheorem{question}[section]{Questão}
%%%---------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{colortbl}
%%%---------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{6}
\fontsize{3.0mm}{3.4mm}
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=cinza,arc=0.0pt,outer arc=0.0pt,colframe=black,boxrule=0.0pt]
\begin{theorem}
Exemple of theorem.
\end{theorem}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @KJO I corrected the error. But it still keeps bugging.

Comment: @KJO I corrected that mistake more. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: @KJO I made the adjustments. But the Portuguese language symbols like 'ç' and 'ã' are coming out wrong or with an error message even with the packages to write in Portuguese.

Comment: @KJO I understood the use of '\ lipsum [1-24]' and '\ lipsum [1-12]'. But I wanted the columns not to be balanced. Could you help me with that?

Comment: @KJO With your tip I solved the problem of symbols in Portuguese. Thank you. But what about columns? How do I make them unbalanced and how to move to the next column with a comma? Let's say \newcolumn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All comments combined try this

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,landscape,a3paper]{extbook}
%------Margins and columns ----------------------------
\usepackage[bottom=1.0cm,top=1.0cm,left=1.0cm,right=1.0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol} % This is so we can have multiple columns of text side-by-side
\columnsep=20pt % This is the amount of white space between the columns in the book.
%------PACKAGES FOR WRITTEN IN PORTUGUESE-------------------
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,brazil]{babel}
%------PACKAGES OF AMERICAN MATHEMATICAL SOCIETY------------
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsxtra}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
%------MATH FONTS PACKAGES----------------------------------
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[mathscr]{eucal}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
%------TIKZ PACKAGES----------------------------------------
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%-----PACKAGE TO PUT THE CAPTIONS IN PICTURES---------------
\usepackage{caption}
\setlength{\captionmargin}{25pt}
%-----PACKAGE TO COMMENTS-----------------------------------
\usepackage{comment}
%-----PACKAGES FOR customize INDEX--------------------------
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{tocvsec2}
\usepackage{makeidx} 
%------ BibTeX and bibliographystyle------------------------
\usepackage{natbib}
%------ Outers packages-------------------------------------
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{upref}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[active]{srcltx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\usepackage{MnSymbol}
%------- packet to write inside colored boxes-----
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\definecolor{cinza}{gray}{0.95}
%\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=cinza,arc=0.0pt,outer arc=0.0pt,colframe=black,boxrule=0.0pt]
%\end{tcolorbox}
%
%----------------------------------------------------------
\newtheorem{theorem}[subsection]{Teorema}
\newtheorem{definition}[subsection]{Definição}
\newtheorem{lema}[subsection]{Lema}
\newtheorem{proposition}[subsection]{Proposição}
\newtheorem{observation}[subsection]{Observação}
\newtheorem{notation}[subsection]{Notação}
\newtheorem{corollary}[subsection]{Corolário}
\newtheorem{exercise}{Exercício}
\newtheorem{exemple}[section]{Exemplo}
\newtheorem{question}[section]{Questão}
%%%---------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{hyperref}%%---------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols*}{6}
\fontsize{3.0mm}{3.4mm}
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=cinza,arc=0.0pt,outer arc=0.0pt,colframe=black,boxrule=0.0pt]
\begin{theorem}
Exemple of theorem.
\end{theorem}
\end{tcolorbox}
\lipsum[1-12]
\vspace{3cm}
\lipsum[1-8]
\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

It is possible to nest multicols however the general recommendation is don't since there can be problems downstream however some users find that with care by avoiding spillage from one to the other it meets their needs. It may be simpler to re asses your target usage and find other ways (packages) to place boxes and floats, perhaps look at how large posters (baposter tikzposter etc) handle such issues